# Mail sending error asp.net

Tags: email, asp.net, web-hosting

I've developed an application in asp.net MVC.

My application sends a mail using my smtp server.

It works fine in my local PC/network, But when I send mail using my web server (my website is hosted in [godaddy.com](http://godaddy.com)), I get the following error:

Error: Insufficient permissions for setting the configuration property 'port'. (D:\Hosting\6295866\html\web.config line 177)

My web.config file settings are as follow:

```
<configuration>
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="vikas.patel@sufalamtech.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network host="mail.sufalamtech.com" port="2626" defaultCredentials="false" password="mypassword" userName="vikas.patel@sufalamtech.com" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

My SMTP server use the 2626 port to send email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send mail via GoDaddy, I think you need to send via their SMTP server address **relay-hosting.secureserver.net** on port 25, and make sure you have a valid from address.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360214/cannot-send-email-in-asp-net-through-godaddy-servers

Comment: Thanks, I've logged a ticket/question to DoDaddy, I think they block the port for security reason.